# AJAX only saving the first letter of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an AJAX request which serializes form data and sends it to a database. When teh data is serialised, I see it renders the full text inout, but when it stores it in the database, it only saves the first letter of every word?

For example it will serialize this to be sent:

> splashText=Silver Glaze

but the database will save if there is none line:

> S

if there are multiple rows in the submitted table data is captured in the database as follows:

> row 1 would = S
>   row 2 would = i

Where as I'm trying to get it as follows:

> row 1 would = Silver Glaze
>   row 2 would = Next option selected in the row and so on...

The serialised data POSTed is as follows (with 2 rows):

```
job_ref=3123&job_desciption=321&sil_cost=1&sil_cost_price=2.00&sub_total=119.75&item_name%5B%5D=1&item_quantity%5B%5D=1&item_unit%5B%5D=1&item_glass%5B%5D=110&item_splash%5B%5D=20&item_colour%5B%5D=-&item_HQuan%5B%5D=1&item_HDiam%5B%5D=2.25&item_CQuan%5B%5D=1&item_Total%5B%5D=56.25&item_cil_row%5B%5D=0.000001&item_name%5B%5D=1&item_quantity%5B%5D=1&item_unit%5B%5D=1&item_glass%5B%5D=110&item_splash%5B%5D=20&item_colour%5B%5D=-&item_HQuan%5B%5D=1&item_HDiam%5B%5D=7.5&item_CQuan%5B%5D=1&item_Total%5B%5D=61.50&item_cil_row%5B%5D=0.000001&glassText=6mm Toughened Extra Clear6mm Toughened Extra Clear&splashText=Rainbow SparkleRainbow Sparkle&holeText=22mm27mm
```

The code to serialise the form:

```
  var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&glassText=' + $('.item_glass').children("option").filter(":selected").text() + '&splashText=' + $('.item_splash').children("option").filter(":selected").text() + '&holeText=' + $('.item_HDiam').children("option").filter(":selected").text();
```

The + is for getting the text value of the input instead of the value. I think this may be the problem but im not sure how to fix it?

PHP Post:

```
 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_name"]); $count++)
 {
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_items
  (order_id, item_name, item_quantity, item_unit,item_glass, item_splash, item_HQuan,item_HDiam,item_CQuan,item_colour,item_total,user_id)
  VALUES (:order_id, :item_name, :item_quantity, :item_unit,:item_glass,:item_splash,:item_HQuan,:item_HDiam,:item_CQuan,:item_colour,:item_total,:user_id)";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':order_id'   => $order_id,
    ':item_name'  => $_POST["item_name"][$count],
    ':item_quantity' => $_POST["item_quantity"][$count],
    ':item_unit'  => $_POST["item_unit"][$count],
    ':item_glass'  => $_POST["glassText"][$count],
    ':item_splash'  => $_POST["splashText"][$count],
    ':item_HQuan'  => $_POST["item_HQuan"][$count],
    ':item_HDiam'  => $_POST["holeText"][$count],
    ':item_CQuan'  => $_POST["item_CQuan"][$count],
    ':item_colour'  => $_POST["item_colour"][$count],
    ':item_total'  => $_POST["item_Total"][$count],
    ':user_id'   => $user_id
   )
  );
 }
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 if(isset($result))
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
}
```

It is a dynamic table being saved. Thats what the count is.

To put context on the dynamic table here is a screenshot:

[image: Dynamic table]:

Comment: Can you confirm and post here what text you are getting in php?

Comment: Please provide the php code.

Comment: edited with php code

Comment: `$_POST["item_name"]` is most likely a string, not an array. Thus, doing `$string[0]` will return the first letter of `$string`

Comment: @blex this works for all other values other than the string values. All others are float

Comment: Can you post an example value for your JS variable `form_data` so we can reproduce the issue and play with it?

Comment: If you're sending `splashText=Silver Glaze` then `$_POST["splashText"]` is indeed a string.  So `$_POST["splashText"][$count]` would be one character from that string.

Comment: That works if you take that out but saving now saves them as a large string in each row. Is thier a way of saving each indvidual row like [$count] does?

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: It's not clear what you mean.  What is the actual data being posted to the server?  What changes have you made to the server-side code since asking the question?  What isn't correct?  Please provide a minimal but complete example of the problem in the question.

Comment: So currently with ':item_splash'  => $_POST["splashText"][$count] it sends only the first letter of each row and saves it as multiple different rows in the database. Without [$count] each row is the data entered into every row. For example: if, in the table 2 rows are entered with splashText[1] = 123 and splashText[2] = 345 the database would store 123345 in every row, but should save row 1 as 123 and row 2 as 345.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: How could splashText[1] = 123 and splashText[2] = 345 ever possibly be true if `splashText` is the string "Silver Glaze"?  You're going to have to present a complete and clear example of the problem in the question above.  Currently your vague descriptions in comments are hard to follow and don't make much sense.  Show the data being sent to the server, the server-side code saving that data, the resulting saved data, and indicate specifically which resulting data is incorrect.

Comment: I have updated the post with as best description as I can and have included a screenshot of the actual table and serialized form data

Comment: use `name="item_name[]"` (array)in your form. access it in your php script like this `$_POST["item_name"][$i]` thru looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't provide the html code, so I assume the 'Review Quote' button is the submit button. So, try this:

change from

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&glassText=' + $('.item_glass').children("option").filter(":selected").text() + '&splashText=' + $('.item_splash').children("option").filter(":selected").text() + '&holeText=' + $('.item_HDiam').children("option").filter(":selected").text()
```

To:

```
var glassText = '';
$('.item_glass').each(function(){
    glassText+='&glassText[]='+$(this).find(":selected").text().replace(' ','+');
});

var splashText = '';
$('.item_splash').each(function(){
    splashText+='&splashText[]='+$(this).find(":selected").text().replace(' ','+');
});

var holeText = '';
$('.item_HDiam').each(function(){
    holeText+='&holeText[]='+$(this).find(":selected").text().replace(' ','+');
});

var form_data = $(this).serialize() + glassText + splashText + holeText;
```